# Loop destructuring in Clojure

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Is there a way for destructuring the `recur` bindings in a loop?
So for example if i want to let `y` stay unchanged in

```
(loop [x 1 y 1] (if (< x 5) (recur (inc x) _ ) (println "result:" x y))
```

I know this is not possible, but how could i get a similar thing like `_` in sequential destructuring for `recur`?

Comment: If you want y to stay uncahnged, why don't you just keep it out of the loop/recur? (let[y 1] (loop [x 1] (if...

Comment: i'm going to use it in other parts of the loop under other conditions using `cond` instead of `if`

Comment: y will still be available for use in cond ot whatever you want from the definition in let. recur is like calling a function, you can't call (+ 3 _) either.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `y` never changes inside the `loop`, you can just wrap everything in a `let` that binds a value to `y`, or even place your `loop` in a function that receives `y` as an argument.

## `let`

```
(let [y 1]
  (loop [x 1]
    (if (< x 5)
      (recur (inc x))
      (println "result:" x y)))
```

## `defn`

```
(defn loop-with [y]
  (loop [x 1]
    (if (< x 5)
      (recur (inc x))
      (println "result:" x y)))
```